# COMO Substituir dados entre tabela

Tags: php

Bom dia. Estou com um problema, estou criando um sistema para melhorar o atendimento dos alunos, que passam por uma liberação de MAC para poder acessar o WI-FI da faculdade.

Criei uma aba de cadastro onde todos os cadastros vão para o banco, por exemplo `bd_cadastros` e para tabela `tb_mac`, até ai tudo certo.

Agora vou criar uma página onde um usuário veja todos os MAC cadastrados e faça a liberação. Meu problema é o seguinte, quero colocar ao lado de cada MAC cadastrado um botão que mova os MAC liberados da tabela `tb_mac` para a tabela `tb_macsliberados`. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Bem-vindo(a) ao [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/)! Já tentou alguma coisa? Tem alguma dúvida específica? Aqui não é o melhor lugar para pedir exemplos ou tutoriais genéricos. Sugiro que faça o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e leia sobre [Como perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Essa movimentação inclui duas operações. Primeiro, ao selecionar o endereço Mac a ser liberado você realizar um novo insert na tabela **tb_macsliberados**, ao fim do insert você aplicar um delete no registro correspondente na tabela: **tb_mac**

Já o botão mencionado é algo simples, isso vai ser apresentado na camada de visualização ("html, js e css").

Eu pessoalmente iria optar por deixar tudo na mesma tabela, bastaria criar uma coluna do tipo "boolean" e marcar ela como "true" ao liberar um endereço Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode user `INSERT INTO SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO tb_macsliberados (`mac`, `idDoMac`)
SELECT `mac`, `idDoMac`
  FROM tb_mac
  WHERE idDoMac = "1"
```

Nesse caso ele irá "mover", na verdade inserir todos os dados que existe no `tb_mac` onde o idDoMac`é igual a 1 para o`tb_macsliberados`.

> Você precisa apenas restringir o WHERE e ele irá "mover" o que deseja para lá.

Você pode criar também um UNIQUE no `mac`, afim de não publicar registros.